# Having problems with fetching data in client Next 13 & Sanity

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch-api, sanity

I've tried a lot of different ways of fetching data in client components in Next 13, but none of them seem to work. I also installed a library, `react query` but it doesn't seem to work either. Can someone show me an example of fetching data in a client component?

Here is the code that would work on a regular server component:

`app/users/page.js`

```
import { getUsers } from "../sanity/queries"

export default async function UsersPage() {
  const users = await getUsers();
  
  return (
    <main className="pt-[100px]">
      { JSON.stringify(users) }
    </main>
  )
}
```

`sanity/queries.js`

```
import { groq } from "next-sanity";
import client from "./client";

export async function getUsers() {
  return client.fetch(
    groq`*[_type == "user"]`
  )
}
```

How could I transform this code into a client component? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the useQuery hook provided by the react-query library. Here's an example:

```
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import { groq } from "next-sanity";
import client from "../sanity/client";

export default function UsersPage() {
  const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery("users", async () => {
    return client.fetch(
      groq`*[_type == "user"]`
    );
  });

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  }

  return (
    <main className="pt-[100px]">
      { JSON.stringify(data) }
    </main>
  );
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. I get this error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://rc70arjs.apicdn.sanity.io/v2021-10-21/data/query/production?query=*%5B_type+%3D%3D+%22user%22%5D' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to add localhost:3000 to your CORS origins in your sanity manager.  You should be able to find it under the API tag in your project window.

Answer (score 0):

for the one who facing issue with CORS

```html
It still doesn't work. I get this error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'rc70arjs.apicdn.sanity.io/v2021-10-21/data/query/…*%5B_type+%3D%3D+%22user%22%5D' from origin 'localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

you can go to sanity project,click API tab, click webhook,in CORS origin section add http://localhost:3000